# Ver Query de Nhibernate

Tags: c#, sql, nhibernate

hoy los molesto porque tengo una consulta realizada con Nhibernate, que es la siguiente:

```
var e = _session.CreateCriteria<EstadoReclamo>()
                .Add(Restrictions.Eq("EtiquetaId", etiquetaId))                
                .CreateCriteria("GruposReclamo", "grupo")
                    .Add(Restrictions.IdEq(motivo.GruposReclamo[0].Id))                  
                .SetMaxResults(1)
                .UniqueResult<EstadoReclamo>();
```

Mi duda, y lo que eh estado buscando desde ya, pero sin ver nada que me ayude demasiado, es si hay alguna forma de ver esa sentencia como un query, es decir, que me muestre la sentencia pura en un string, tal como "select * from EstadoReclamo......". Espero sea clara mi pregunta. Muchas gracias desde ya.

Comment: Por qué no utilizas directamente el [SQL Server Profiler](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-mx/sql/tools/sql-server-profiler/sql-server-profiler?view=sql-server-ver15) ?

Comment: Hola, porque no uso sql server, uso informix. En la empresa donde trabajo usan esa bdd aun...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podrías usar directamente el [SQL Server Profiler](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-mx/sql/tools/sql-server-profiler/sql-server-profiler?view=sql-server-ver15) en dado caso que no quieras...

---

Puede poner en su archivo `app.config` / `web.config` en el nodo `configSections` algo como esto:

```
<section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler,log4net"/>
```

en el nodo de configuración:

```
<log4net>
  <appender name="NHibernateFileLog" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender">
    <file value="logs/nhibernate.txt" />
    <appendToFile value="false" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%d{HH:mm:ss.fff} [%t] %-5p %c - %m%n"  />
    </layout>
  </appender>
  <logger name="NHibernate.SQL" additivity="false">
    <level value="DEBUG"/>
    <appender-ref ref="NHibernateFileLog"/>
  </logger>
</log4net>
```

Y no olvides llamar

```
log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
```

al inicio de su aplicación, o para poner

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(Watch=true)]
```

en la `asambleainfo.cs`

En la configuración, establezca la propiedad "**show_sql**" en verdadero.

---

Si prefiere el código en lugar de la configuración, el siguiente fragmento creará el registrador NH adecuado con un simple accesorio de consola.

```
var hierarchy = (Hierarchy) LogManager.GetRepository();
var logger = (Logger) hierarchy.GetLogger("NHibernate.SQL");
logger.AddAppender(new ConsoleAppender {Layout = new SimpleLayout()});
hierarchy.Configured = true;
```

Puede que tanga que usar `TraceAppender` en lugar de `ConsoleAppender` para ver esto en la ventana de salida de Visual Studio y agregar `logger.Level = Level.Debug`.

> **Fuente:** [How do I view the SQL that is generated by nHibernate?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/129818/8933039)
>
> Otros enlaces que pueden ser de interés:
>
> - [How to read sql generated by NHibernate in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8244083/8933039)
> - [Displaying NHibernate SQL in Visual Studio’s Output Window](https://suspendedwithpay.wordpress.com/2009/04/03/displaying-nhibernate-sql-in-visual-studios-output-window/)
> - [How to know query generated by Fluent NHibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/819040/8933039)

Comment: Muy buena tu respuesta J. Rodríguez, muy completa, gracias!

Comment: @cpistiner que bueno que te haya servido de ayuda.